# How to draw Functor Diagram with tikz-cd and any framed environment

Tags: tikz-cd

I would like to draw a diagram like the one in the image with tikzcd and any framed environment(e.g. itembox).[image]

For me, using tikz is complicated and cumbersome and I would prefer to avoid it.
I want to use **tikz-cd**.
(Drawing with tikz-cd is easy, because we can use this tool. https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/ )

I thought this diagram was drawn using itembox (ascmac.sty) and minipage.
And I tried, but I did not get the desired results.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Postscript:
Our apologies. I tried to output the following code.
This was not the desired output.
[image]

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.30\linewidth}
\begin{itembox}[l]{$C$}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
             \& a \arrow[rd,"g"] \&  \\
            b \arrow[ru, "f"] \arrow[rr,"g\circ f"] \&  \& c \\
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{center}
\end{itembox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.10\linewidth}
    $\overset{F}{\longrightarrow}$
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.30\linewidth}
\begin{itembox}[l]{$D$}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
             \& F(a) \arrow[rd,"F(g)"] \&  \\
            F(b) \arrow[ru, "F(f)"] \arrow[rr,"F(g\circ f)"] \&  \& F(c) \\
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{center}
\end{itembox}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: If you tried, then please show what you tried. Otherwise your question looks very much like the typical do-it-for-me post.

Comment: I'm sorry. I added the method I tried.

Comment: Can you specify what changes you would like to see. I assume the arrow with the F should be vertically centred. What else?

Comment: I don't want the size of the itembox to change depending on the size of the tikzcd diagram.
I want the size of the two itemboxes to be the same.
Also, I want to write the F and the arrow in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- align the minipages in the `c`enter instead of the `b`ottom to get the arrow in the centre
- to give the boxes a fixed size, use another set of minipages within them

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ascmac}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{itembox}[l]{$C$}
  \begin{minipage}[c][.6\linewidth]{\linewidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
             \& a \arrow[rd,"g"] \&  \\
            b \arrow[ru, "f"] \arrow[rr,"g\circ f"] \&  \& c \\
        \end{tikzcd}
     \end{minipage}     
\end{itembox}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.10\linewidth}
    \centering
    $\overset{F}{\longrightarrow}$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{itembox}[l]{$D$}
   \begin{minipage}[c][.6\linewidth]{\linewidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
             \& F(a) \arrow[rd,"F(g)"] \&  \\
            F(b) \arrow[ru, "F(f)"] \arrow[rr,"F(g\circ f)"] \&  \& F(c) \\
        \end{tikzcd}
     \end{minipage}
\end{itembox}%
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!
I appreciate your very good solution.

Comment: @nat-cat You're welcome!